# How do I set it that my if statements variable is the same as my function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, selection

Apologies for the phrasing of the question as I'm not entirely sure how to put it.
What I've been trying to do is to get the user to input their input, and then when my if statement is implemented and it calls on their input, I can ask the if statement to see if their input is equal to another variable that is set up by a function.
I'm not sure that makes sense but here's my code and I'll try to explain a bit more.

```
def randomint(a,b):
    return random.randint(a,b)
def random_line(fname, num):
    f1 = open(fname ,"r")
    lines = f1.readlines()
    return lines[num]
def random2(fname, num):
    f2 = open(fname ,"r")
    line1 = f2.readlines()
    return line1[num]
def f1():
    print(random_line('songs.txt' , nu))
def f2():
    random_line('songnames.txt' , nu)
nu = randomint(0,4)

f1()
f2()
a2 = input("what is the songs name\n")
if a2 == f2():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

So as you can see, my functions above calls on an external file set by the parameter's file name and then the random number of the lines assigned. What I'm trying to do is set it so that when I use the if statement and it checks to see

```
if a2 == f2():
```

if it is equal to the same thing. Provided they input the right answer, I want it to output yes to just to make sure it's working. My problem is that when I run the code and I try to get the "yes", I get the output as no despite knowing the answer.
I'll show how it runs when I do it.

```
Post Malone C

yes
Circles
no
```

This is just one example but this is what happens. Wondering how to make sure it outputs yes, sorry if I worded it horribly, not entirely sure how to type it out.

Comment: `f2()` **always** returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `return` in your `f1()` or `f2()`. It should be:

```
def f2():
    return random_line('songnames.txt' , nu)
```